# sitecore mvc return view with viewmoldel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, placeholder, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm working on a MVC website with Sitecore. In a specific Controller I return a (partial)view with a `ViewModel`, however the page is only showing the plain (partial)view which I returned. So there is no styling at all. This sounds about right but the issue for me is that I expected the full page with all other partial views who are configured via Sitecore on the presentation details.

I'm trying to avoid using `ViewBags` because the `ViewModel` is there and I think it is and looks better to use the `ViewModel`.

My code is very straightforward:

The Controller returns the view like below:

```cs
return PartialView("NameOfTheView", viewModel);
```

And in the page I'm just parsing the `ViewModel` items, nothing special there.

I'm using a placeholder in Sitecore. This is where the view should be shown. Could it be that the placeholder is issue here?

Hope my question is clear and someone knows the answer obviously ;-)

Comment: How do you call your controller action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all the help guys!

After checking all you suggestions I found my answer in a 'related' question ([Sitecore MVC form postback does not return a full layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287910/sitecore-mvc-form-postback-does-not-return-a-full-layout?rq=1)) his question described exactly my problem only in less words and better description...

In my case my mistake was using `@Html.Sitecore().FormHandler("Controller", "Action")` instead of `@Html.Sitecore().FormHandler()` which solved the problem.

Comment: Any insight on why this is the case? I was also doing it the same way you were doing it

Answer (score 2):

I would first verify that you are using a "Controller Rendering" and that it is inserted into the placeholder you expect. This can be done using the Presentation Details dialog.

Next, it's not necessary to return a partial view from your controller. A traditional partial view in ASP.NET MVC requires a layout with a call to @RenderBody() and/or calls to @Html.Partial(). This functionality is handled by Sitecore's presentation model (using placeholders). Instead, simply return a View("/path/to/view.cshtml", viewModel) from your controller and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

Is you controller returned by some *@Html.ActionLink(...)*?

If yes then everything is correct. To avoid this problem you can try to use *@Ajax.ActionLink(...)*

Answer (score 0):

If the view is rendering without any style, then this is typically because Sitecore has not been able to resolve an item for the requested view.

Ensure that you are accessing your controller action via a defined route, and that the route has the scItemPath property set to the sitecore item that contains your layout details.